# No such file or directory error when including a header file in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to include a header file in my cpp file but I am getting an error saying no such file or directory.

Things I have done:

1. Added the header file in `c_cpp_properties.json`

`"includePath": ["C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\dev"],`

2.Added include path to args in `tasks.json` file.

```
"args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-I", // ADDED THIS 
            "C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\dev" //AND THIS
        ],
```

Before doing these two things, there was an error in the cpp file saying that it cannot open the header I was trying to include.

But after doing that it says, `no such file or directory #include <experimental/filesystem>`, which is in the header file that I am trying to include.

I have been struggling with this for soo long now so any help at all would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

Here is the include code in the library I am trying to include that is causing the error

```
#if defined(USE_EXPERIMENTAL_FS) || defined(FORCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FS)
    // C++14
    #define _SILENCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATION_WARNING
    #include <experimental/filesystem>
    namespace _gfs = std::experimental::filesystem::v1;
```

Everything after the if clause is gray-ed out so it means it wont be run, but the error is still showing.

Edit 2:

I also just noticed that in the problems section it is saying, `"experimental/filesystem: No such file or directory gcc[310, 11]"`
and gcc is a compiler, so it is a problem with my compiler?

Comment: You may need to enable  c++17 and / or upgrade your compiler. msys2 provides a mingw gcc-10.2

Comment: @drescherjm I just tried that and it gave me loads of error messages and at the end it said  `undefined reference to __imp_SHCreateMemStream` which seems to imply that there is something wrong with the library but it works fine in visual studio.

Comment: I did both of those things. Tried using the compiler that visual studio uses to compile everything properly and it still does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

the solution for this is easy, I also did a lot of search to find it, and when I stumbled here and could not find a solution, felt almost desperate XD.

just link `-lshlwapi` with g++

and every thing should work.

also to mention this is the full list of dependencies I needed to link
`-lgdiplus`, `-lopengl32`, `-lgdi32`, `-ldwmapi`, `-lwsock32`, `-lshlwapi`